# can't able to curl google even after using proxy

Tags: php, curl, google-custom-search

I'm trying to scrape data from google results and for this doing curl request which works fine for few searches but after that it starts showing "Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your" then tried using proxy but still getting the same however; the ip is now changed after uisng proxy but not the error.

Error Image

[image]

Here is the code i'm using;

```
  $curl=curl_init();
  
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY,             'ip'); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT,         'port');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD,'user:pass');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        if($result === FALSE) {
    die(curl_error($curl));
}
        curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Did you even read the error message?

Comment: You are trying to circumvent policies that they have in place for bots. Those are there for a reason. Google has APIs for most of their services that don't require using a scraper.

Comment: Google actively tracks down what they perceive as “_unorthodox_ attempts to request their servers” and intervene. This includes automated requests made from scripts with things like `curl`. With the default settings, `curl` even uses a user agent string like `curl/7.54`, so Google knows right away that you “are” not a browser. :)

Comment: Yes, I did and I'm looking for a way to bypass the above security and i know this is to stop what i'm doing.

Comment: If there was a simple way of bypassing this, Google would fix their algorithm

Comment: @dulange Okay! You mean its impossible to perform curl even with proxy?

Comment: @NicoHaase I know about the steps google can take but that's not a answer we can expect from a developer.

Comment: Why isn't that an answer to be expected from a developer? Choose their official and supported APIs if you seek long-term success in accessing their data. Everything else is unprofessional and can stop working at any time

Comment: @JamesSon It depends on what proxy you are using and what kind of information (i.e. headers) they relay from your original request. If you really want to go on this adventure, make sure, the request that Google receives looks as much like a normal request from any generic browser and comes from a non-suspicious IP. Expect it to be a tedious task, tough, as you can expect Google to spend a lot of effort and brainpower on such defense measures.

Comment: I rather doubt that this will all be based on just the _initial_ requests for such a result page. A real browser would request embedded assets, maybe make AJAX requests in between, etc. pp. If all those "characteristics" are missing across a couple of consecutive requests - then you'll probably quickly get classified as a "suspicious" requester, and then it will be CAPTCHA time again. (Using a headless browser _could_ perhaps help to make one appear more "genuine", at least for a while.)

Comment: @CBroe you're pointing me to the right direction AJAX request would be better as what i'm doing many sites already did but i don't know what they are using but after analysing their Network tab on chrome get to know that they are doing through AJAX.

Comment: @dulange Oh you mean proxy quality also matter so in this case Residential proxy will perform better than other as it will make look more natural than other.

Comment: @NicoHaase You need to be unprofessional sometimes as it helps to findout the bugs and lopehole so being a professional guy all time doesn't help in innovative.

Comment: Yeah, searching for loopholes is sometimes a good idea. But don't spend too much energy on that, Google has way more manpower for this game

Comment: @NicoHaase if a developer work with this mindset then he/she will not invest energy on finding bugs or security loopholes of big companies thinking that they have more manpower.

Comment: And if I deploy a feature to a production system that works just because I use any currently existing bug that might get closed anytime, my customer is pretty unsatisfied when the system suddenly stops working just because I thought I could be smarter than Google

Comment: @NicoHaase you're going to the wrong direction if you find any bugs or something like that then a developer responsibility is to report to the authority not to exploit the bug for personal profit. :)